# Como usar um vetor alocado dinamicamente retornado de uma função em C?

Tags: c

Tenho um vetor de tamanho dinâmico que foi criado em uma função e preciso retorná-lo para a função principal.

A função que retorna é a seguinte:

```
int* uniao(int *v1, int n1, int *v2, int n2){
    int *v3;
    int i, j = 0;

    //Aloca dinamicamente v3
    v3 = (int*) malloc((n1 + n2) * sizeof(int*));

    //Preenche o vetor com o v1
    for(i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        v3[i] = v1[i];
    }

    //Preenche o vetor com v2
    for(i = n1; i < (n1 + n2); i++){
        v3[i] = v2[j];
        j++;
    }

    return v3;
}
```

Como poderia usá-lo na função main?

Estava tentando isso:

```
pAux = uniao(&v1, n1, &v2, n2); //Ponteiro Auxiliar recebe &v3

for(i = 0; i < (n1 + n2); i++){
    printf("\n%i", *pAux[i]);
}
```

Mas a aplicação acaba fechando antes de exibir o vetor. :v

Comment: Adicionado a função "união"

Comment: O erro não está nessa parte do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu programa está "fechando" antes de exibir o resultado pois ele está causando uma [falha de segmentação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falha_de_segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Esse erro ocorre quando uma programa tenta acessar (para leitura ou escrita) um endereço na memória que está reservado para outro programa.

Ao utilizar o `*` (asterisco), também conhecido como [`operador de dereferência`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) na linha:

```
printf("\n%i", *pAux[i]);
```

Você está tentando acessar o endereço de memória contido em `pAux[i]`, que no seu caso, trata-se do valor inteiro contido em um dos elementos do seu buffer dinâmico apontado por `pAux`, que certamente não se trata de um endereço de memória válido.

Não existe a necessidade de usar um `operador de dereferência` nesse caso, e o correto seria:

```
printf("\n%i", pAux[i]);
```

Ou então, se você realmente gosta de usar o `operador de dereferência`, combinado com uma [`aritmética de ponteiros`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponteiro_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#Aritm.C3.A9tica_de_ponteiros_em_C_e_C.2B.2B) simples, você pode fazer algo como:

```
printf("\n%i", *(pAux + i));
```

Segue uma versão corrigida e melhorada do seu programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Calcula tamanho de um vetor estatico */
#define sizeofvec(a)   (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

int * uniao( int * v1, int n1, int * v2, int n2 )
{
    int i = 0;

    /* Aloca dinamicamente v3 */
    int *v3 = malloc((n1 + n2) * sizeof(int));

    /* Preenche o vetor com o v1 */
    for( i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        v3[i] = v1[i];

    /* Preenche o vetor com v2 */
    for( i = 0; i < n2; i++ )
        v3[n1 + i] = v2[i];

    /* Retorna uniao dos vetores */
    return v3;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;

    int v1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int v2[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    int * pAux = uniao( v1, sizeofvec(v1), v2, sizeofvec(v2) );

    for( i = 0; i < (sizeofvec(v1) + sizeofvec(v2)); i++)
        printf("%d ", *(pAux + i));
    printf("\n");

    free(pAux);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Se você quiser ir um pouco mais além, segue uma outra versão do mesmo programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Calcula tamanho de um vetor estatico */
#define sizeofarr(a)   (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

void uniao( int **v3, int *n3, int *v1, int n1, int *v2, int n2 )
{
    /* Calcula tamanho de v3 */
    *n3 = n1 + n2;

    /* Aloca dinamicamente v3 */
    *v3 = malloc( (*n3) * sizeof(int) );

    /* Preenche o vetor com o v1 */
    memcpy( *v3,  v1, sizeof(int) * n1 );

    /* Preenche o vetor com v2 */
    memcpy( (*v3) + n1, v2, sizeof(int) * n2 );
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int * pAux = NULL;

    int v1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int v2[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    /* Ponteiro Auxiliar recebe v3 */
    uniao( &pAux, &n, v1, sizeofarr(v1), v2, sizeofarr(v2) );

    /* Exibe vetor */
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", pAux[i]);
    printf("\n");

    /* Libera memoria dinamicamente alocada */
    free(pAux);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente o maior problema é passar como ponteiro algo que já um ponteiro. Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* uniao(int *v1, int n1, int *v2, int n2) {
    int *v3 = malloc((n1 + n2) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) v3[i] = v1[i];
    for (int i = n1, j = 0; j < n2; i++, j++) v3[i] = v2[j];
    return v3;
}

int main(void) {
    int v1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int v2[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int *pAux = uniao(v1, 3, v2, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", pAux[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/12vmIq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jzqbtyqt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/PassArgument.c).

Uma coisa para pensar. Quem fará a liberação da memória? Neste caso está vazando. O `main()`? Mas ele não alocou, porque ele deveria ser responsável por isso? A filosofia básica do C é: alocou, libera. Como Não pode fazer isto dentro de `uniao`, porque a alocação dinâmica é justamente para manter o objeto vivo depois dela, teria que fazer na função `main()` e passar o ponteiro alocado como parâmetro. Feito isto tudo fica mais fácil.

Comment: É o que eu faria neste caso (talvez não em outro exemplo que fosse usado em outros lugares).

Comment: Todo `malloc()` pede um `free()`!

Comment: @Lacobus acho que aqui foi proposital deixar assim para simbolizar a memória vazada